# Bing Maps API for Android GPS navigation

Tags: android, bing-maps

I want to use only place autocomplete for lat/long data.
But cannot understand this paragraph from "license agreement" disallow me to use it?

> present or alert an end user to individual maneuvers of a route in any
>   way that is synchronized with the end-user’s sensor-based position
>   along the route, (e.g. “real-time” navigation);

I want to build the route with help of Bing Maps (Autocomplete API for addressees) and then trigger the GPS navigation without any use of Bing Maps's data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Bing maps controls or services to build an application that provides turn-by-turn guidance directly to the user in that application is prohibited by the terms of use.
If you are using Bing maps services to determine the lat/long of a destination and then handing that position off to some other application (like the built-in maps app) to do the turn-by-turn guidance, that would be permitted.

Answer (score 1):

That line is simply saying that you're not allowed to use their data to create your own turn-by-turn navigation app. It doesn't sound like you're doing that, so it's probably fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I'm just too afraid.. since Google totally close all G-Map
APIs for any kind of  link with GPS navigation